# What is the URL pattern for image thumbnails + sizes?

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, urls, media-library

Often times I need to get the URL of a specific image in the media library but I am not doing it in the context of a PHP script. I need to put a  element in in a widget that doesnt have WYSIWYG, or give the URL to an 3rd party affiliate, or something like that. I know I can get the original URL from the media library. Is there a pattern that that WordPress uses to get the URL of a specific image size (like thumbnail or medium)?

If I had an image in the media library at,

```
/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/example.jpg
```

... what would the URL of the thumbnail be?

I tried things like appending `-thumbnail`, `_thumbnail`, `-medium`, and `_medium` to the filename, before the extension, but none work.

Answer (score 1):

In general the format is:
    originalfilename-300x203.jpg, where 300x203 are the dimensions of the thumbnail.

However, there are a few things that mean you can't rely on this:
- if the user has edited the file within WP, the filename will change
- if the original image is smaller than the dimensions you specify, that thumbnail will not have been generated.

I think if I needed to do this, I'd create a 'just for me' PHP file or Wordpress template in which I pass it the ID of the image and it generates the URL for me using WordPress's own image functions to which you can pass the size (e.g. get_the_post_thumbnail_url).